# WPF color definitions confusion

Tags: c#, wpf, colors

Why is in WPF the color "Gray" darker then the color "DarkGray". My logic says that "DarkGray" shoud be darker.

Should it not be  LightGray, Gray, Darkgray?

Comment: There some strange entries in the Colors class. Read my article [Definitive Guide to WPF Colors, Color Spaces, Color Pickers and Creating Your Own Colors for Mere Mortals](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5296124/Definitive-Guide-to-WPF-Colors-Color-Spaces-Color) explaining them in detail and how to deal with them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These color names actually [come](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa358802%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from the [CSS Color Module Level 3 W3C Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/) and the strange definition of Gray and Dark gray actually comes from merging the X11 and web standards. To quote [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names):

> Perhaps most unusual of the color clashes between X11 and W3C is the
>   case of Gray. In HTML, Gray is specifically reserved for the 128
>   triplet, i.e. 50% gray. However, in X11, ‘gray’ was assigned to the
>   190 triplet, i.e. 75%, which is close to W3C ‘Silver’, and had
>   ‘Light Gray’ at 211 and ‘Dark Gray’ at 169 counterparts. This
>   resulted in W3C’s ‘Gray’, at 50%, actually being significantly darker
>   than ‘Dark Gray’, at 66%.

Answer (score 3):

While I agree that the naming suggests that `Colors.DarkGray` would be darker than `Colors.Gray`, [DarkGray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors.darkgray%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is defined and documented to be `#FFA9A9A9`, and [Gray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors.gray%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is defined to be `#FF808080` (which is darker).

That being said, you can define any color you wish, and not use the predefined system colors.

Answer (score 1):

**Color Hex:**

If you want a better control of the colors you should use hexadecimal code for colors!

**Here some examples:**

- http://www.colorhexa.com/
- http://www.color-hex.com/

Comment: its not about the control but the about the, sometimes irradical, microsoft logic

Comment: Read the original question!